# Consulta de una lista en Linq no me realiza el filtro con el where

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

Tengo la siguiente consulta que me mapea a una clase...

```
List<ProductosViewModel> ListaProdFiltrado = (from p in Db.ProductoIntelectual
                        select new ProductosViewModel
                        {
                        TipoProducto = p.TipoProducto,
                        NombreProducto = p.NombreProducto,
                        FechaInicial = p.FechaInicial,
                        FechaFin = p.FechaFin,
                        Ambito = p.Ambito,
                        ProductoTiene = p.ProductoTiene,
                        RealizadosEvento = p.RealizadosEvento,
                        Idioma = p.Idioma,
                        NombreEstudiante = p.NombreEstudiante,
                        Estado =p.Estado,
                        Eliminado = false,
                        FechaRegistro = p.FechaRegistro
                        }).ToList();
```

Esta lista la realizo con un where.. (igual lo hice en el select) pero muestra los 1000 registros

```
ListaProdFiltrado.Where(p => Filtro.TipoArticulo == null || p.TipoProducto.Contains(Filtro.TipoArticulo))
   .Where(p => Filtro.Ambito == null || p.Ambito.Contains(Filtro.Ambito))
   .Where(p => Filtro.ProductoTiene == null || p.ProductoTiene.Contains(Filtro.ProductoTiene))
   .Where(p => Filtro.Idioma == null || p.Idioma.Contains(Filtro.Idioma));
```

según lo que vi en este [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EWB3POlVkGk) para ver como realiza la consulta coloque la lista con .ToString

```
var q = ListaProdFiltrado.ToString();
```

pero no me muestra la consulta sql que deberia ser...

```
SELECT
   TipoProducto,
   NombreProducto,
   FechaInicial,
   FechaFin,
   Ambito,
   ProductoTiene,
   RealizadosEvento,
   Idioma,
   NombreEstudiante,
   Estado,
   Eliminado,
   FechaRegistro 
FROM
   Maestros.Productos 
WHERE
   (
      Ambito = N'NACIONAL'
   )
   AND 
   (
      Idioma = N'ESPAÑOL'
   )
```

el resultado de la consulta es....

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y debería mostrar 82 Y SIEMPRE Muestra 1000 registros, pareciera que no realiza el where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var lista = ListaProdFiltrado.Where(p => Filtro.TipoArticulo == null  ||p.TipoProducto.Contains(Filtro.TipoArticulo))
                             .Where(p => Filtro.Ambito == null || p.Ambito.Contains(Filtro.Ambito))
                             .Where(p => Filtro.ProductoTiene == null ||  p.ProductoTiene.Contains(Filtro.ProductoTiene))
                             .Where(p => Filtro.Idioma == null || p.Idioma.Contains(Filtro.Idioma));
```

No estás asignando la consulta hecha a ninguna variable, por eso te devuelve siempre los mismos registros, porque como tal no estás guardando este filtro. En el código que te pongo si filtras y el resultado lo almacenas en la **variable lista**, la cual va a tener el subconjunto de la lista original filtrada.